# SQL : Error converting data type varchar to numeric. - I want to add percent sign "%" in data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Error converting data type varchar to numeric. -  I want to add percent sign "%" in data

```
 SUM (Convert(Varchar, CASE 
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        = 0  THEN 1
        WHEN e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        >= 29 THEN 2
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        >= 14 THEN 3
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        >= 8 THEN 4
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        <= 7  THEN 5


        ELSE 1

     END)*.05 + '%') as total
```

Sample Output: 2.5%

Comment: You can try to run a nested 'select' to capture the total of all complexity before grouping

Comment: Can you give some sample?

Answer (score 0):

I think You need something like this

```
select  Convert(Varchar(50), SUM (CASE 
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        = 0  THEN 1
        WHEN e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        >= 29 THEN 2
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        >= 14 THEN 3
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        >= 8 THEN 4
        WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
        <= 7  THEN 5


        ELSE 1

     END) * 0.5) + '%' as total
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like below ( 2012+ )

```
CONCAT (

        CAST(

            SUM (  

                CASE 
                    WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
                    = 0  THEN 1
                    WHEN e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
                    >= 29 THEN 2
                    WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
                    >= 14 THEN 3
                    WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
                    >= 8 THEN 4
                    WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
                    <= 7  THEN 5
                    ELSE 1
                END *.05 

                ) AS VARCHAR(MAX)

            ) , '%') as total
```

Or 
from below SQL 2012 use this

```
 CAST(

            SUM (  

                CASE 
                    WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
                    = 0  THEN 1
                    WHEN e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
                    >= 29 THEN 2
                    WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
                    >= 14 THEN 3
                    WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
                    >= 8 THEN 4
                    WHEN  e.complexity = 'Simple'  AND datediff(DAY, e.entry_date, a.datetime_stamp)
                    <= 7  THEN 5
                    ELSE 1
                END *.05 

                ) AS VARCHAR(MAX)

            ) + '%' total
```